# If/Then formula to treat a number as negative conditional upon accompanying text

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, formulas

I am creating a spreadsheet to track rent owed from agents at a real estate company. I have drop-down lists created to pick from the agent and the type of transaction (`Payment`, `Rent Incurred`, `Credit Issued`, `Fee Issued`, `Payment Reversed`, `Copier Usage`). What I want is to just enter the number in the Amount field without making it a negative, and have a formula that will add it or subtract it based on the type of transaction it is. I want this:

```
If C2="Payment" OR "Credit Issued", then D2=POSITIVE
If C2="Rent Incurred" OR "Fee Issued" OR "Payment Reversed" OR "Copier Usage", then D2=NEGATIVE
```

Is it possible to do a formula like that in conjunction with a running balance?

Like this:

```
Date           Agent         Transaction         Amount          Balance
8/25/15        Mike          Payment             $150.00         -$150.00
9/1/15         Joyce         Rent Incurred       $200.00          $ 50.00
9/1/15         Mike          Rent Incurred       $150.00          $200.00
9/1/15         Chris         Rent Incurred       $250.00          $450.00
9/6/15         Chris         Payment             $250.00          $200.00
9/15/15        Joyce         Fee Issued          $ 25.00          $225.00
9/21/15        Joyce         Payment             $225.00          $  0.00
```

I guess I want my balance formula to be like this:

```
=if(c2,"Payment""credit issued",d2*-1,c2,"Rent incurred""fee issued""copier usage""payment reversed",d2)+c1
```

Does this make any sense at all?

Answer (score 1):

A formula that may be entered in E2, and filled down:

`=N(E1)+D2*IF(OR(C2="Payment",C2="Credit Issued"),-1,1)`

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Updated question....I'm now trying to have a corresponding table with each individual agents' balance in it, pulling info from the main ledger. I had planned on doing this:

=sumif($b$2:$b$70,g2,$d$2:$d$70)

How do I incorporate the negative number formula?

Thanks again!

Comment: `=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER($D$2:$D$70*IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$2:$C$70,{"Payment";"Credit Issued"},0)),-1,1),$B$2:$B$70=G2)))`

Comment: Hmm....this is giving me 76.1 in whatever cell I try to use it in, and that number has no relevance at all in the context of this sheet. I'd like to understand more about these formulas so I can work out where the breakdown is. Any ideas?